save enum in database as enum
I'd like to save entity with parameter "type" which need to be as ENUM in database.
CREATE TYPE type AS ENUM ('TYPE1','TYPE2','TYPE3');

My entity looks like:
@Column(name = "type")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
val type: TypeEnum

In previous version it was text in db.And i write migration like this
ALTER TABLE table1
ALTER COLUMN type TYPE type USING type::enum_type;

And getting error lumn [type] in table [table1]; found [type (Types#VARCHAR)], but expecting [smallint (Types#TINYINT)]
Some history:
in migrationOne:     type      text        NOT NULL
Than i have task to change text to enum ib db.
I do this:
CREATE TYPE type_enum AS ENUM ('TYPE1','TYPE2','TYPE3');
ALTER TABLE table1
ALTER COLUMN type TYPE type_enum
    USING CASE
              WHEN type = 'TYPE1' THEN 'TYPE1'::type_enum
              WHEN type = 'TYPE2' THEN 'TYPE2'::type_enum
              WHEN type = 'TYPE3' THEN 'TYPE3'::type_enum
    END;

`
And have error when try to create entity.
I think the problem when hibernate try to save entity with parameter type like string not like type_enum in db

Did you already have data in table1?

Yes,i have data.But at this moment i using empty db and i get error when create entity

Here's a step-by-step approach to address this:
Create the ENUM Type:
Ensure that the ENUM type is created correctly in your database:
SQL
CREATE TYPE type AS ENUM ('TYPE1', 'TYPE2', 'TYPE3');

Update the Entity Mapping:
Verify that your entity mapping is correct:
Java
@Column(name = "type")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
val type: TypeEnum

Write the Migration Script:
Here's a refined migration script to handle the type conversion and potential data loss:
SQL
ALTER TABLE table1
ALTER COLUMN type TYPE type
USING CASE 
    WHEN type = 'TYPE1' THEN 'TYPE1'::type
    WHEN type = 'TYPE2' THEN 'TYPE2'::type
    WHEN type = 'TYPE3' THEN 'TYPE3'::type
    ELSE NULL -- Handle unexpected values
END;


still getting: could not execute statement [ERROR: column "type" is of type type_enum but expression is of type character varying   Подсказка: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression(i rename type to type_enum for simplicity)
